How to add 2 different models as child node in DevExpress WPF
I have this class:
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Competency> Competencies { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Competency>();

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
}

And this code works for me:
<Page>
    <Page.Resources>
        <model:Employee x:Key="employees" />
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Team}" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Row.Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="3,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Employee}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Border Padding="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#FFC3CEDC" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="130" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Row.FirstName}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="3,0,0,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Row.LastName}" Margin="3,0,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- TreeListControl for Teams -->
        <dxg:TreeListControl x:Name="teamEmployeesTree" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding TeamsItems}">
            <dxg:TreeListControl.View>
                <dxg:TreeListView 
                     TreeDerivationMode="HierarchicalDataTemplate" 
                     AutoExpandAllNodes="True" 
                     ShowCheckboxes="True" 
                     AllowRecursiveNodeChecking="False"
                     NewItemRowPosition="Top" 
                     AllowPerPixelScrolling="True"
                     TreeColumnFieldName="Name"
                     NavigationStyle="Cell"
                     AllowDragDrop="True"
                     ShowDragDropHint="False"
                     ShowNodeImages="True"
                     UseEvenRowBackground="True"
                     EnterMoveNextColumn="False"/>
            </dxg:TreeListControl.View>
            <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Name" />
            <dxg:TreeListColumn FieldName="Competencies"/>
        </dxg:TreeListControl>
    </Grid>
</Page>

Now what I want is to have another type of child node, so I need some kind group by thing here:
Team (root)
 - "Employees" (fixed node text, and when I click on this to present all employees for that team)
   --Emp1
   --Emp2
 - "Competencies" - (fixed node text, and when I click on this to present all employees for that team)
   -- Competency1
   -- Competency2

Also I need checkbox "Is TeamLead" but only for employees.
Is this possible and to have different columns inside each nodes group?
Update #1:
I took approach by courtesy of @BionicCode  approach #1.
Here is my updated and filled data in codebehind:
public partial class TeamsAdmin : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<Team> TeamItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Team>();
    public TeamsAdmin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        TeamItems = InitData();
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Team> InitData()
    {
            // Create some sample employees
            var employee1 = new Employee { Id = "1", FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
            var employee2 = new Employee { Id = "2", FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Smith" };
            var employee3 = new Employee { Id = "3", FirstName = "Alice", LastName = "Johnson" };

            // Create some sample competencies
            var competency1 = new Competency { Id = "1", Name = "Leadership" };
            var competency2 = new Competency { Id = "2", Name = "Communication" };
            var competency3 = new Competency { Id = "3", Name = "Technical Skills" };

            // Create EmployeeDetails and CompetencyDetails
            var employeeDetails = new EmployeeDetails { TeamId = 1 };
            employeeDetails.Children.Add(employee1);
            employeeDetails.Children.Add(employee2);
            employeeDetails.Children.Add(employee3);

            var competencyDetails = new CompetencyDetails { TeamId = 1 };
            competencyDetails.Children.Add(competency1);
            competencyDetails.Children.Add(competency2);
            competencyDetails.Children.Add(competency3);

            // Create a sample team and add the details
            var team1 = new Team { Id = 1, Name = "Team A" };
            team1.Details.Add(employeeDetails);
            team1.Details.Add(competencyDetails);

        // Add the team to the TeamsItems collection
        TeamItems.Add(team1);

        return TeamItems;
    }
}

Regarding the XAML part for now I have this:
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:dfk.Pages"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:dfk.Models"
    xmlns:bh="clr-namespace:dfk.Test1"
    xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="av"
    x:Class="dfk.Pages.TeamsAdmin"
    Title="Upravljanje Timovima"
    Height="1080"
    av:DesignWidth="1200">

    <Page.Resources>
        <model:Employee x:Key="employees" />
        <model:Competency x:Key="competences" />
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Team}" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Details}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:EmployeeDetails}" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="Employees" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:CompetencyDetails}" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="Competencies" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <!--<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Employee}">
            ...
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:type Competencies}">
            ...
        </DataTemplate>-->

    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <dxg:TreeListControl 
            ItemsSource="{Binding TeamItems}" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" 
            EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True">
            <dxg:TreeListControl.View>
                <dxg:TreeListView 
                    TreeDerivationMode="ChildNodesSelector"
                    ChildNodesSelector="{StaticResource childrenSelector}"/>
            </dxg:TreeListControl.View>
        </dxg:TreeListControl>
    </Grid>
</Page>

But still Im not sure about XAML part, should I use HierarchialDataTemplate or?

You have three general options:
#1 Modify the data structure.
If you have the chance to modify the data structure you could simply add another level e.g. a Details property that acts as a group.
Team.cs
public class Team
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<ITeamDetail> Details { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ITeamDetail>();
}

ITeamDetail.cs
public interface ITeamDetail
{
  int TeamId { get; set; }
}

ITeamDetailGeneric.cs
public interface ITeamDetail<TChild> : ITeamDetail
{
  ObservableCollection<TChild> Children { get; };
}

CompetencyDetails.cs
public class CompetencyDetails : ITeamDetail<Competency>
{
  public int TeamId { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<Competency> Children { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Competency>();
}

EmployeeDetails.cs
public class EmployeeDetails : ITeamDetail<Employee>
{
  public int TeamId { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<Employee> Children { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
}

This will give you the following tree structure:
Team
|
|__Employees
|  |__Employee1
|
|__Competencies
   |__Competency1

Then adapt the templates to the new structure:
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Team}" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Details}">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:EmployeeDetails}" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
  <TextBlock Text="Employees" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:CompetencyDetails}" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
  <TextBlock Text="Competencies" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Employee}">  
  ...
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:type Competencies}">
  ...
</DataTemplate>

#2 Modify the DataTemplate or the ControlTemplate of the TreeView control.
If you can't modify your data structure and your tree is a simple one level structure then you can display the Empoloyess and Competencies lists in a dedicated ListBox that you define in the template for the Team root. I don't recommend this as this introduces issues with navigation as the two ListBox elements would be interpreted as a single node by the TreeView. This solution yields the worst results.
#3 Create a custom control.
As a third solution you can use a custom control that is based on `Expander controls:
Generic.xaml
<Style TargetType="TeamView">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="TeamView">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}>
          <ListBox.ItemsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="Team">
              <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
                <StackPanel>
                  <Expander Header="Employees"
                            Margin="8,0,0,0"
                            Padding="4,0,0,0">
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" />
                  </Expander>
                  <Expander Header="Competencies"
                            Margin="8,0,0,0"
                            Padding="4,0,0,0">
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Competencies}" />
                  </Expander>
                </StackPanel>
              </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListBox.ItemsTemplate>
        </ListBox>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

TeamView.cs
A highly specialized control.
You can enhance extensibility of your application by making this control to accept a DataTemplate for each of the two levels by adding two more dependency properties of type DataTemplatewhich you then bind to the ListBox.ItemsTemplate property of the two internal ListBox elements. This way changing the data models will not break this control's template. For simplicity I have avoided this overhead in this example.
You can also override the default ListBoxItem template to remove the highlight behavior (just define the plain template without any triggers).
class TeamView : Control
{
  public IList<Team> Teams
  {
    get => (IList<Team>)GetValue(TeamsProperty);
    set => SetValue(TeamsProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty TeamsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(Teams),
    typeof(IList<Team>),
    typeof(DelayButton),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  static TeamView()
  {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TeamView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TeamView)));
  }
}


The check box to show the value of the Employee.IsLead property could be added to the DataTemplate:
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Employee}">
  <CheckBox x:Name="IsTeamLeadCheckBox" 
            IsChecked="{Binding IsLead}"
            Content="{Binding Name}" />
</DataTemplate>

Or use a trigger to hide (not collapse) the CheckBox when unchecked (only show for the lead):
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Employee}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <CheckBox x:Name="IsTeamLeadCheckBox" 
              IsChecked="{Binding IsLead}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
  </StackPanel>

  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLead}"
                 Value="False">
      <Setter TargetName="IsTeamLeadCheckBox" 
              Property="Visibility"
              Value="Hidden" />  
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>

Alternatively, you can also override the item container's template to add the CheckBox before the ContentPresenter. But I personally would prefer to add the CheckBox to the DataTemplate for this particular case as it is only relevant for the Employee node.

Thanks for detailed answer.
What you think? which approach should I take?
I wuld like to have multiple DataTemplates (in this scenario employee and competence), because for ecah type I would like different presentation.
Can you update the whole xaml code?
And I dont ned ListBox compnent, I need just to group the data as I emntioned to employees and competencies.

I personally would prefer changing the data model (#1). Adding the Details properties adds value and it avoids all the hassle to adjust the view. All suggestions allow you to define individual DataTemplates.  I have updated #1: class structure and also now show the templates.

In #3 the ListBox is presenting a group. First group all Employee items. Second group all Competency items. That's what the ListBoxes are for. Each is wrapped into a Expander to enable expand/collapse.

Ok, and I have error for ITeamDetail interface saying
interfaces cannot contain instance fields regarding  ObservableCollection<TChild> Children;

OK I set {get;}
Can you please just put some dummy example for these datatemplates and how can I call them in my treelistview?
I would like to have whole xaml file if possible. I took approach #1 and trying to get workable solution. Tnx

I have added a template for each node to #1 below the sketch of the tree structure. Haven't you seen it?

You just have to add your custom layout content where the "..." are (the last two DataTemplates).

can you put in your answer also treelistview updated?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

There is nothing changing with the TreeListView. We only changed the data structure. The tree root is the same. And for the child nodes I have added the rnecessary data templates. Just add these templates to App.xaml, populate the tree data models and runyour application.

https://i.imgur.com/OeaXuu0.png
I cant expand Team A.

This is because your TreeListControl is configured to use a child node selector to pick the child nodes. But you are using HiearchicalDataTemplate to define the visual structure. Just set the TreeListView.TreeDerivationMode accordingly: <dxg:TreeListView TreeDerivationMode="HierarchicalDataTemplate" />
